# How to set query value to output variable in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, join, stored-procedures

Here is my SQL query, when I execute it, the error shown below is occurring. I am new to SQL Server, can anyone explain what the reason for this error is? How can I set this SQL JOIN query to variable?

```
ALTER PROC spGetFullLog
    @PatientID varchar(10),
    @PatientD nvarchar(255) output
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @PatientD = First_Name,
        Last_Name,
        dbo.CalculateAge(Date_of_Birth) AS Age,
        Admitted_Date, Patient_Condition,
        Medicine_Prescribed, Treatment_Advice,
        Treatments_Given, Date_of_Discharged,
        Diagnosis, Treatments,
        Date_of_operation, Typpe_of_operation,
        Condition_Before, Condition_After
    FROM 
        Patients_Main
    FULL JOIN
        Admitted_Patients ON Patients_Main.Patient_ID = Admitted_Patients.Patient_ID
    LEFT JOIN
        Discharged_Patients ON Patients_Main.Patient_ID = Discharged_Patients.Patient_ID
    LEFT JOIN 
        Patient_Consultation_Details ON Patients_Main.Patient_ID = Patient_Consultation_Details.Patient_ID
    LEFT JOIN 
        Operation ON Patients_Main.Patient_ID = Operation.Patient_ID
    LEFT JOIN
        Patient_Conditon ON Patients_Main.Patient_ID = Patient_Conditon.Patient_ID
    WHERE
        Patients_Main.Patient_ID = @PatientID
END
```

This is the code I used to execute this stored procedure

```
DECLARE @Details nvarchar(255)
EXECUTE spGetFullLog 'PT0001', @Details output
print @Details
```

This is the error

> Msg 141, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spGetFullLog, Line 7
>   A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Comment: Try running that again **WITHOUT** `PatientD =`. My guess is that you will not get an error message. If I'm correct, it means that you either provide variables to all the extracted fields or to none. If you need the procedure to return a record set with all the fields, you can simply get all the values into local variables, do whatever you have to do (with the variable `PatientD`) and then imply **`SELECT`** all the variables before return.

Comment: @Spiderman: _complex and tricky_?? Are you serious?

Comment: One additional observation: You are setting the condition as `WHERE Patients_Main.Patient_ID = @PatientID`. Try `WHERE Patients_Main.Patient_ID = First_Name` (after removing the assignment at the beginning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get explains what you are doing wrong very clearly - You can't set variables values and also retrieve values in one query. you have to use 2 queries to get the results you want:

```
ALTER PROC spGetFullLog
    @PatientID varchar(10),
    @PatientD nvarchar(255) output
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        @PatientD = First_Name
    FROM 
        Patients_Main
    WHERE
        Patient_ID = @PatientID;

    SELECT 
        Last_Name,
        dbo.CalculateAge(Date_of_Birth) AS Age,
        Admitted_Date, Patient_Condition,
        Medicine_Prescribed, Treatment_Advice,
        Treatments_Given, Date_of_Discharged,
        Diagnosis, Treatments,
        Date_of_operation, Typpe_of_operation,
        Condition_Before, Condition_After
    FROM 
        Patients_Main
    FULL JOIN
        Admitted_Patients ON Patients_Main.Patient_ID = Admitted_Patients.Patient_ID
    LEFT JOIN
        Discharged_Patients ON Patients_Main.Patient_ID = Discharged_Patients.Patient_ID
    LEFT JOIN 
        Patient_Consultation_Details ON Patients_Main.Patient_ID = Patient_Consultation_Details.Patient_ID
    LEFT JOIN 
        Operation ON Patients_Main.Patient_ID = Operation.Patient_ID
    LEFT JOIN
        Patient_Conditon ON Patients_Main.Patient_ID = Patient_Conditon.Patient_ID
    WHERE
        Patients_Main.Patient_ID = @PatientID
END
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not only assign partial column to variable. You should do it separately.

```
ALTER PROC spGetFullLog
    @PatientID varchar(10),
    @PatientD nvarchar(255) output
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
         @PatientD = First_Name
    FROM  Patients_Main
    WHERE  Patients_Main.Patient_ID = @PatientID


     SELECT 
    @PatientD = First_Name
    Last_Name,
    dbo.CalculateAge(Date_of_Birth) AS Age,
    Admitted_Date, Patient_Condition,
    Medicine_Prescribed, Treatment_Advice,
    Treatments_Given, Date_of_Discharged,
    Diagnosis, Treatments,
    Date_of_operation, Typpe_of_operation,
    Condition_Before, Condition_After
FROM 
    Patients_Main
FULL JOIN
    Admitted_Patients ON Patients_Main.Patient_ID = Admitted_Patients.Patient_ID
LEFT JOIN
    Discharged_Patients ON Patients_Main.Patient_ID = Discharged_Patients.Patient_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    Patient_Consultation_Details ON Patients_Main.Patient_ID = Patient_Consultation_Details.Patient_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    Operation ON Patients_Main.Patient_ID = Operation.Patient_ID
LEFT JOIN
    Patient_Conditon ON Patients_Main.Patient_ID = Patient_Conditon.Patient_ID
WHERE
    Patients_Main.Patient_ID = @PatientID
END
```

Comment: @Nolan i think this code still occurring such error,check this line again :)  
   PatientD = First_Name
    Last_Name,

Comment: you mean the @PatientD should be first name concat last name? then will be: @PatientD=ISNULL(FirstName+' ','')+ISNULL(LastName,'')

Answer (score 0):

I thought it is worth explaining you why what you are doing makes no sense.

You are trying to assign a value to the variable `@PatientD`. [Assuming that the statement would be syntactically legal, which is not] The value to be used is a result of filtering out data, so only after the filter process is completed, the assignment takes place. Hence, using the same variable as part of the filter would mean that the variable does not have any value assigned during the filtering process. Kind of **CATCH 22** thing.

Hope this made things clearer for you.

Comment: Not really. There are two variables - Patient**I**D and PatientD. The first is used to filter the query and the second is used to output results.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, OOOPPPSS!!!!! Well, someone would need to explain the OP a few things about variables' naming... Thanks for the correction.